# Why Chrome shows 200 response code when Express is sending back a 304?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, caching, frontend

My Node.js Express API is sending back a 304 Not Modified response code, but in Chrome's network panel, I'm seeing that the response is a 200.  Why is that?

When I disable Chrome's cache, I see that the size of the request goes up significantly.  Around 1.1 KB when cache is **disabled** and around 250 B when the cache is **enabled**.  So, it seems pretty clear that the behind the scenes use of ETag/If-None-Match headers is doing its job.

However, I would expect Chrome to show a 304 code, instead of a 200, when its retrieving the API response data from its local cache.